# The message should be an instance of \Zend_Mail when upgrade to Magento 2.3.1

Tags: order-email, magento2.3.1, send-mail

I have upgraded my magento version to 2.3.1. On previous version i.e on 2.2.6 the sendgrid was working properly.

Now I can see that sendgrid is not compatible with 2.3.1. What to do..

Because of this We have issues regarding mail sending. Also is there any  issues regarding to normal mail delivery without SMTP in magento 2.3.1?

Is there any temporary patch or solution available on this fourm?

Comment: You can move to gmail smtp.

Comment: I think SendGrid not compatible with  Magento2.3.1

Comment: Any luck on this issue, I am also facing same issue, even I also try Mageplaza SMTP nut it give me same error "The message should be an instance of \Zend_Mail"